# Kafka Stream data change add to new topic or stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a topic that feeds into a stream. That stream has a status field. Is it possible to add to an object to another topic if say status changes from 'pending' to 'complete' all within KSQL. I can do this easily enough in code but would like to keep it all within Kafka if possible?

Comment: Please explain what "add to an object to another topic" means. You can `filter` messages, by status, to other topics, sure

Comment: I don't want to just filter on status. I want to essentially conditionally filter on change of status. By add to another topic I mean. Add a new message to a topic if a stream witnesses a specific change in value. I think what I'm asking is can you have triggers or at least pseudo triggers in Kafka KSQL.

Comment: A `CASE` or `WHERE` statement is the best you can do for a conditional filter. Then you can chose to stream those to a new downstream topic whenever the upstream topic gets those events

Answer (score 1):

As a sketch of a possible approach, if you use `latest_by_offset(column, 2)`, you'd have an array of the last two statuses.

With that array, you may be able to use a `CASE` statement to identify when those statues are "pending" and "complete" (in that order).  When that happens, you can emit on to the next stream as you suggest.